# How can make MySQL use indexes i created

Tags: mysql, database, performance, indexing

I have a table named `t_owecoupon`, and it has an index named `index_cpn_endvalidity`.

```
+-------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name           | Seq_in_index | Column_name |   Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| t_owecoupon |          1 | index_cpn_endval   |            1 | ENDVALIDITY | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
```

(sorry but I can't have a better view of my queries results)
MySQL never uses this index... 
For example, here is the result of an explain on a simple query

```
explain select * from t_owecoupon where endvalidity > date('2015-01-01');
+----+-------------+-------------+------+------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys    | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t_owecoupon | ALL  | index_cpn_endval | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 307017 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

The output is always the same, it says that I could use the index I want in "possible keys"... The query above is an example, I have a more complexed query and it doesn't use the index either.

I tried: use index, group by my indexed column, order by my indexed column, but the output of the explain is always the same.

How can I Make MySQL use my index?

Thanks for your help.

The real query -

```
SELECT  
    date_format(endvalidity,'%Y-%m') as mois, cpn.ABONNE_id, cpn.statut, regulation, cpn.id
    FROM powecpn.t_owecoupon as cpn, t_oweabonne as abo
    WHERE cpn.ABONNE_id = abo.ID
    and abo.usi != '0000000000'
    and date_format(DATE_ADD(endvalidity, INTERVAL 6 MONTH),'%Y-%m') > @DATE_ANNEE_MOIS
    and endvalidity < DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(str_to_date(CONCAT(@DATE_ANNEE_MOIS,'-1'),"%Y-%m-%d")),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    group by mois, cpn.ABONNE_id, cpn.ID
```

Comment: Please show the definition of the index.

Comment: Dont use the date() function. Pass the date as a  string

Comment: Please indicate in the query what table `endvalidity` is in.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Where does `@DATE_ANNEE_MOIS` come from?

Comment: In your first query, what percentage of the table matches `endvalidity > date('2015-01-01')`?

Comment: In the first query, what happens if you say `WHERE endvalidity > NOW()`?

Comment: the variable @date_annee_mois comes from a shell script and is passed through the command mysql. I tried with "> now()" and it did the same

Comment: What's the index cardinality value?

Comment: I think, the query is try to scan whole table and index is not getting used. Try to do use/force index and see if its making any difference

Comment: When MySQL doesn't use an index, it's not necessarily a bad thing - it does this for a reason, which means your index isn't selective as much (too many values that are the same) and it does this to make the search quicker. Are you experiencing any performance problems or is this just another case of programming OCD?

Comment: I'm sure index is a good thing , his cardinality is 100 and the table has more than 3 million lines. If i use force it works and the query lasts 8 seconds whereas it lasts 22 minutes without using the index..